# why is undefined useSession data after excuting signIn callbacks and redirecting create user page

Tags: oauth, next-auth, next.js13

I want to create OAuth using next-auth v4, next13^, app directory.
when redirecting join page after excuting signIn callback, 'const {data} = useSession()'is undefined.
how to solve this?

```
callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      try {
        const check = await checkToken({
          provider: account?.provider || '',
          id_token: account?.id_token || '',
          access_token: account?.access_token || '',
        });
        return check === 'login' || `/user/${check}`;
      } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof AxiosError) {
          if (e.response?.data.error.code === 4029) alert(e.message);
          return true;
        }
      }
      return true;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      return url;
    },
    async session({ session, user, token }) {
      const newSession = {
        ...session,
        accessToken: token.accessToken,
        user: {
          ...user,
          id: token.id,
        },
      };

      return newSession;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
        token.id = profile?.name;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
```

```
const Sesstion = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};
```

I read document... but I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue I see here is that you are not passing session prop in Session provider. It should look something like this.

```js
const Provider = ({ children, session }) => {
    return <SessionProvider session={session}>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};
```

Comment: thank you, but it's not necessary to passing prop using app directory. And I find the problem..!
Redirects returned by signIn callbacks cancel the authentication flow..!
Thanks to your opinion!!